# How to calculate how many text cells are same in row before (or chosen row)

Tags: excel

I am doing some excel staff, and now need an formula to calculate how many is same and mark them.

Example i have row with 10 cells and want to compare with row under how many same cells are.

I marked same fileds but i need formula which takes range F15:O15 and compare with range F6:O6 to check how many same in these cells.

[image]

Comment: Can't test right now, but something like `=Sum(iferror(Match(F15:O15, F16:O16,0),0)>0)` entered as an Array Formula

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your data is like this:

[image]

As you can see, only 3 cells are identical in both rows (range `D4:F4` = range `D5:F5`)

The formula I've used in cell `D8`is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:J1=A2:J2))
```

And it returns 3 :)

Comment: actually for some reason not working there, i get the #VALUE! in cell.

Comment: @MilenkoJovic How are you typing the formula? IS your Excel in english?

Comment: Yeah, now gives me a results, as you see my picture above. Gives me 2 but third one is not showing. Position is not same. How to avoid this?

Comment: In that case you'll need to check it value by itself with same formula, (that means 10 formulas) and then an 11th formula to sum up results of the 10 previous formulas.

Comment: Is it possible to do with VBA?

Comment: Yes, of course. Post the code you've tried, and post where are you stuck and what errors you get.